# I am getting Timeout expired Error while Migrating application to VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Message: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

I am getting the same issue again.I have checked all my connections are closed.Still it shows same error after some time.

Is there any issue with GC?Is there any utility available that shows me which code is leaking connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue on my live website with millions of users.

I found two solutions and both worked for me.

1)Immediate solution:set Pooling=false in connection string.

2)Later I closed all connections in my code and set Pooling=true.

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/040830.htm